# Css3 animation cheat sheet not working for rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css

I'm using Rails, and trying to implement [CSS3 Animations Cheat Sheet](http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/).

I added `animations.css` to `vender/assets/stylesheets`.  I added `*= require animations` to `application.css`.  I added `@import "animations";` to `home.css.scss`.

The relevant element is `<%= image_tag("pitt.png", size: "336x440", class: "slideLeft", id: "picture") %>`.  Here is it's css styling from `home.css.scss`:

```
#picture {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This leads to no animation.  The image isn't even hidden.  However, if I make the class pullDown instead of slideLeft, the element becomes hidden, but it doesn't appear via an animation (it doesn't appear at all).

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

`animations.css` = http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/css/animations.css

`application.css`

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require jquery-ui/smoothness
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require animations
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: It would really help if you posted your CSS files (namely, your application.css & animations.css)

Comment: Sure, see the edit to my question.

Comment: Also, my apologies for not mentioning or linking to http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/!!